# Why is key binding for CTRL-L key messed up?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, linux

I have run into a Vim key binding issue at the office recently. On the Linux system where I do my development work, while running Vim the <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> key no longer redraws the screen. The `.exrc` file in my home directory does not map the <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> key. The <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> key seems to be mapped to the string "clear".

The value of the `TERM` environment variable is `xterm-256color`, which is what it always has been.

What could cause this issue with the <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> key? I know I can use the `:redraw!` command to refresh the screen, but I would like to use <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> as I have been doing for years.

I ran `vim --version` and received the following

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 30 2020 08:08:00)
```

I should also add that even when I add a mapping for <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> to my `.exrc` file that does not resolve this issue.

Comment: You can show all mapping with the `:map` command. What does `:map <C-L>` return?

Comment: BTW, you should probably take this as an opportunity to rename `.exrc` to `.vimrc`.

Comment: CTRL-L is not mapped to anything

Comment: Then consider the possibility that the problem has its cause elsewhere. In your terminal emulator, maybe?